# Breaking the DateTimePicker by typing in wrong dates

Tags: c#, winforms, telerik

I'm using the DateTimePicker with a customformat (yyyy / MM) and ShowUpDown set to true.

After a few attempts at typing in Dates and clicking on up down the DateTimePicker suddenly threw an IndexOutOfRange exception.

So far I haven't been able to reproduce it willingly, only by typing the numbers from the 1-0 line and ß and ´ in fast Progression while being in the month part it happened a few times again (but not every time when I did this).

As both events

- ValueChanging
- Validating

would Trigger too late (Validating only if I leave the field which I don't during the typing, and ValueChanging already gets a DateTime variable as e.NewValue) I'm not sure how to Approach this Problem, or if it is approachable at all. Thus my question here is: Is there any way to tackle this Problem?

Answer (score 0):

Check the DateTimePicker's **MinDate** and **MaxDate** *properties*. The DateTimePicker won't let you set the date to something that isn't between MinDate and MaxDate.

maybe this help!

Comment: MinDate is set to nothing (in the designer) while maxdate is set to 31.12.9998.  Although the Problem occrured while I just changed the month repeatedly (so the maxdate / mindate shouldn't really be a Problem there or am I on the wrong thought path there?)